# How to implement an advanced look up macro in excel?

Tags: excel

**How do I have to change the following macro code and formula which works for the data and question below(earlier data/question,column F) to make it suitable for Problemstatement (2) and (3) ?**

(1)

**Earlier data**

Colums C,D,E,F

Row 1 4,10,40,F

Row 2 4,12,48,F

Row 3 4,14,56,F

Row 4 3,16,48,F

Row 5 1,18,18,F

Row 6 1,20,10,F

Row 7 0,22,0,0

**Intention of the column F**

1. If Cx <> 0, Fx = Cx
2. If Cx = 0, Fx = the address of the cell in Column C that produces minimum of (C1 * D7 - E1, C2 * D7 - E2, ..., CN * D7 - EN) and is >0.

** Macro code and formula for column F**

Public Function MinimumC()

```
Dim rngCurrent As Range
Set rngCurrent = Application.ThisCell

Dim rngMin As Range
Dim minimum As Long
minimum = 100000000

Dim tmp As Long

Dim rngC As Range
Set rngC = ActiveSheet.Range("C1:C" & rngCurrent.Row - 1)

For Each c In rngC.Cells
    If c.Value2 <> 0 Then
        tmp = c.Value2 * rngCurrent.Offset(0, -2).Value2 - c.Offset(0, 2)
        If tmp < minimum Then
                minimum = tmp
                Set rngMin = c
            End If
        End If
    Next c

MinimumC = rngMin.Value2
```

End Function

Formula in F1 and copy down column F: =IF(C1<>0,C1,MinimumC())

(2)

How do I have to change the macro and formula to archieve the same in the following data format:

**New data 1**

Colums AZ,BA,BB,BC,BD,BE,BF,BG

Row 1 4,4,4,10,10,10,120,444

Row 2 4,4,4,12,12,12,144,444

Row 3 4,4,4,14,14,14,168,444

Row 4 3,3,3,16,16,16,144,333

Row 5 1,1,1,18,18,18,54,111

Row 6 1,1,1,20,20,20,60,111

Row 7 0,0,0,22,22,22,0,**???**

**Intention of the column BG**

1. If(And(AZ>0;BA>0;BB>0);Concatenate(AZ;BA;BB))
2. otherwise, the adress cell of Concatenate (AZ;BA;BB), unequal to 000, to minimize the following difference (AZn*BCx+BAn*BDx+BBn*BEx)-BFn

(3)

How do I have to change the macro and formula from (1) to archieve the same in the following data format:

**New data 2**

Colums AZ,BA,BB,BC,BD,BE,BF,BG,BH,BI,BJ,BK,BL,BM,BN

Row 1 4,4,4,10,10,10,120,444,3,3,3,10,10,10,90,333

Row 2 4,4,4,12,12,12,144,444,3,3,3,12,12,12,108,333

Row 3 4,4,4,14,14,14,168,444,3,3,3,14,14,14,126,333

Row 4 3,3,3,16,16,16,144,333,3,3,3,16,16,16,144,333

Row 5 1,1,1,18,18,18,54,111,2,2,2,18,18,18,108,222

Row 6 1,1,1,20,20,20,60,111,1,1,1,20,20,20,60,111

Row 7 0,0,0,22,22,22,0,?,0,0,0,22,22,22,0,**?**

**Intention of the column BN**

1. If(And(AZ>0;BA>0;BB>0;BH>0;BI>0;BJ>0);0
2. otherwise the adress of the cell either concatenate (AZ;BA;BB) or concatenate (BH;BI;BJ) to minimize (AZn*BCx+BAn*BDx+BBn*BEx)-BFn or (BHn*BKx+BIn*BLx+BJn*BMx)-BNn .In this case i need to find the adress of either concatenate (AZ;BA;BB) or concatenate (BH;BI;BJ) with the min difference and that cell of BN (concatenate) unequal to 000.

I appriciate the help. Thank you very much!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve problem 2, the macro is basically identical. You just need to replace the C range with the AZ range, and change the calculation of `tmp`:

```
Public Function CalcBG()

Dim rngCurrent As Range
Set rngCurrent = Application.ThisCell
Debug.Print rngCurrent.Address

Dim rngMin As Range
Dim minimum As Long
minimum = 100000000

Dim tmp As Long

Dim rngAZ As Range
Set rngAZ = ActiveSheet.Range("AZ1:AZ" & rngCurrent.Row - 1)
Debug.Print rngAZ.Address

For Each c In rngAZ.Cells
    If c.Value2 <> 0 Then
        tmp = ((c.Value * rngCurrent.Offset(0, -4).Value2) + (c.Offset(0, 1).Value2 * rngCurrent.Offset(0, -3).Value2) + (c.Offset(0, 2).Value2 * rngCurrent.Offset(0, -2)) - c.Offset(0, 6).Value2) 'This is your calculation (AZn * BCx) + ... - BFn
        If tmp < minimum Then
            minimum = tmp
            Debug.Print minimum
            Set rngMin = c.Offset(0, 7)
            Debug.Print rngMin
        End If
    End If
Next c


Debug.Print minimum
Debug.Print rngMin.Address

CalcBG = rngMin.Address 'Return the address rather than the value


End Function
```

And the formula:

```
=IF(AND(AZ1>0,BA1>0,BB1>0),CONCATENATE(AZ1,BA1,BB1),CalcBG())
```

Place that in BG1 and copy down Column BG.

**Problem 3**

This added a couple more variables, but the basic structure is the same.

Based on the data, I also assumed that "If(And(AZ>0;BA>0;BB>0;BH>0;BI>0;BJ>0);0" should have been `If(And(AZ>0;BA>0;BB>0;BH>0;BI>0;BJ>0),concatenate(bh,bi,bj)`. Otherwise your values in BO would all be 0. Also, your last column is BO, not BN. :)

Here's the macro:

```
Public Function CalcBO()

Dim rngCurrent As Range
Set rngCurrent = Application.ThisCell
Debug.Print rngCurrent.Address

Dim rngMin As Range
Dim minimum As Long
minimum = 100000000

Dim tmp1 As Long
Dim tmp2 As Long
Dim lowest As Long

Dim rngAZ As Range
Set rngAZ = ActiveSheet.Range("AZ1:AZ" & rngCurrent.Row - 1)
Debug.Print rngAZ.Address

For Each c In rngAZ.Cells
    If c.Value2 <> 0 Then
        '(AZn*BCx+BAn*BDx+BBn*BEx)-BFn
        tmp1 = ((c.Value2 * rngCurrent.Offset(0, -12).Value2) + (c.Offset(0, 1).Value2 * rngCurrent.Offset(0, -13).Value2) + (c.Offset(0, 2).Value2 * rngCurrent.Offset(0, -10).Value2)) - c.Offset(0, 6).Value2
        '(BHn*BKx+BIn*BLx+BJn*BMx)-BNn
        tmp2 = ((c.Offset(0, 8).Value2 * rngCurrent.Offset(0, -4).Value2) + (c.Offset(0, 9).Value2 * rngCurrent.Offset(0, -3).Value2) + (c.Offset(0, 10).Value2 * rngCurrent.Offset(0, -2).Value2)) - c.Offset(0, 14).Value2
        lowest = WorksheetFunction.Min(tmp1, tmp2)
        If lowest < minimum Then
            minimum = lowest
            Debug.Print minimum
            Set rngMin = c.Offset(0, 7)
            Debug.Print rngMin
        End If
    End If
Next c


Debug.Print minimum
Debug.Print rngMin.Address

CalcBO = rngMin.Address


End Function
```

And here is the formula for BO1. Copy down as usual:

```
=IF(AND(AZ1>0,BA1>0,BB1>0,BH1>0,BI1>0,BJ1>0),CONCATENATE(BH1,BI1,BJ1),CalcBO())
```

There's a lot of repetition among those macros, and they could probably be condensed. But they should do what you need.

One note: The macros won't differentiate between equal minimum values. For example, in problem set 3, the two calculations (AZn ... - BFn and BHn ... - BNn) return the same value, 6, which also happens to be the minimum value among all the calculations. In this case, it returns the first address (AZn ... - BFn). So in Problem 3, you will get the answer $BG$6 in BO7, even though $BG$6 and $BO$6 both satisfy the conditions. Your requirements didn't specify what to do in case there was more than one minimum value, so I left it as it is.

Let me know if you need any help with the above.

Comment: thanks for seeing it through. This code you provided still produces #value, when instead it should give me the minimum. Maybe its because I have changed step 1. into an if(or)formula? Its probably some mistake i have made somewhere. As I will be busy with work this week I hope you do not mind if i contact you again, in case necessary, by the end of the week?! This is the last part of coding needed to simulate a CCA auction, my master thesis, hence i really really really appriciate you putting in so much effort and time!:-)

Comment: Feel free to contact me any time. The code works on all the test data I have, so to help troubleshoot I would probably need to see your changes. But I'm happy to help however I can.

Comment: I implemented some changes and now it works just fine. thank you so much for ur time and effort!!